# Unsatisfied version (jspdf) in stackblitz

Tags: stackblitz

When I try to install jspdf in stackblitz.com, its showing the below error.
Failure: Unsatisfied Version Range
Unable to resolve package
Please try installing a different version or range

[image]

Thank You

Bobbin